# Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1 Security Configuration- adding user and role

Tags: spring-roo

I ran below roo command after adding my controller,

`security setup`

I saw that the command created couple of tables in mySql database like login_role,user_login,user_login_role.

Now when I am starting my application on localhost:8080,
I am getting the login window , 
but I am still not able to add user or configure security in the generated application.

I researched out on this topic where it was mentioned to configure applicationContext-security.xml file or SecurityConfiguration java file. I could not find any of these in the application.

Please suggest how I can authentication in my application generated through Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1

Answer (score 1):

If you uses the `security setup` command as you said in the description, the `login_role`, `user_login`, `user_login_role` tables should not be generated. These tables will be generated only if you use the `security setup --provider SPRINGLETS_JPA`.

Check https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/#security-setup

Anyway, if you use the `security setup` command without any extra parameter, you should use `user` as username and you should obtain the password from the console log during the application deployment. This is the behaviour of the default configuration of the Spring Security starter on Spring Boot applications.

You should check https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html

On the other hand, remember that Spring Roo helps you to configure and maintain the project, but you're able to include extra code that you need. 
In this case, you need to create a [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) to configure the users that will be able to access to your application or to configure the [AuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) (in the previous Configuration class) that will be used to authenticate users from the DB, WebService, etc.

Hope it helps,